# Magento - Override other Route of another Module

Tags: magento, module, routes

I'm using the clever cms module to manage some basic cms pages. Now I want to add some custom behaviour to one of the routes the clever cms is using. An Example:

```
example.com/cms/page // <- a normale cms page
example.com/cms/category // <- another module should do it's stuff here
```

When I make a new module, I can only override the whole cms route, and not plug myself in the `cms/category` only.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a new controller, this is easy; just make use of the native ability to map multiple controller directories to a frontname. In your module config:

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <cms>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <your_module after="Mage_Cms">Your_Module</your_module>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </cms>
    </routers>
```

This will allow requests to map to *Your/Module/controllers/CategoryController.php*.

Comment: Hum, this doesn't seem to work. Maybe my question wasn't accurate. Clever CMS let's you configure your own routes via the admin panel. Like this url: `example.com/info/`. Under this route, there can be multiple routes like `example.com/info/product_1` or `example.com/info/products/books`. I now wnat to have something like: `example.com/info/category`. Your code lets me have a route like: `example.com/cms/category`. If I change `cms` to `category` in the xml it doesn't work.

Comment: Ah, I have no knowledge of how Clever CMS adds routes. If you want to add a new frontname to the standard router (e.g. site.com/category) you will need to add config XML for that frontname, but I suspect this is not your goal

Comment: Hum, no, thats not what I want. Ok, thanks I keep digging in the clever cms code.